# Does vCenter/VMWare have a tool/command that shows Actual Usage (Written Data) within thick Provisioned Storage in a DataStore

Tags: disk-space-utilization, vmware-vcenter, datastore, usage, thick-provisioning

I am very familiar with our storage footprints. All our storage is thin provisioned (is there any Enterprise Array these days that does not use thin provisioning. Don't think so). And of course see size of Total storage, the Total Allocated (provisioned), AND exactly what has been ACTUALLY written to the that provisioned storage. My problem is that the VM team continually over-provision. We have ESX clusters that have been given 100 TB 4 years ago, and are barely at 30% utilization. And the problem is that thee VM team keeps adding more storage, BECAUSE they base their analysis on PROVISIONED storage and think they are running out if adding new VMs, expanding use.

My question is simple: IS THERE NO way in vCenter/VMWare for a thick provisioned space to be able to see the ACTUAL "USED" storage (actual Written Data). In Unix I can do a simple command "df" that will display what was provisioned for a filesystem (Provisioned Space in VM), and what has actually been written to that filesystem. There must be a command/utility that will report on actual Written Data numbers. Without having to change all the 1 PB of ESX clusters to thin provisioned. Your help will be highly appreciated, Please. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but see if this is what you're looking for. This was captured using RVTools. - https://www.robware.net/rvtools/

[image]

Comment: Joe, yes, this looks exactly as to the data I was looking for.  Now I need to know more about RobWare.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help...